# Why Payload Factory Mediator builds XML with default name space?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to generate XML through Payload Mediator in WSO2 sequence without a name space. Example:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
          <XmlRoot>
            <a>$1</a>
            <b>$2</b>
            <c>$3</c>
            <d>$4</d>
          </XmlRoot>
        </format>
        <args>
          <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.a"/>
          <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.b"/>
          <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.c"/>
          <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.d"/>
        </args>
      </payloadFactory>
```

Above one generates xml like below:

```
<XmlRoot xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <a>Paper</a>
    <b>en-US</b>
    <c>en-US</c>
    <d>USD</d>
</XmlRoot>
```

Instead of (that is my goal)

```
<XmlRoot>
    <a>Paper</a>
    <b>en-US</b>
    <c>en-US</c>
    <d>USD</d>
</XmlRoot>
```

I know this namespace is gets from sequence root element. how to avoid or eliminate this auto generated name space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the default name space by adding empty namespace ( `xmlns=""`) in payload factory mediator

e.g <`XmlRoot xmlns="">`

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
          <XmlRoot xmlns="">
            <a>$1</a>
            <b>$2</b>
            <c>$3</c>
            <d>$4</d>
          </XmlRoot>
        </format>
        <args>
          <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.a"/>
          <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.b"/>
          <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.c"/>
          <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.d"/>
        </args>
      </payloadFactory>
```